# How does AWS Provisioned IOPS EBS volumes compare to dedicated disk

Tags: amazon-ec2, performance, amazon-web-services, hard-drive, amazon-ebs

In the past, no one can answer the performance difference as they are not well documented. Now AWS offer **Provisioned IOPS EBS volumes**

Let say you now you buy **1000** IOPS, how does this value compare to the performance of a single 7200 RPM SATA disk?

Comment: Do you have a 7200 RPM SATA disk?

Comment: Sorry, but the "value" of various service offerings is something only you can evaluate for your particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS gives ballpark figures for a 7200 RPM drive of ~75-100 IOPS.